# pycharm: indexing installed package instead of sources root

Tags: pycharm, pythonpath, project-structure

I cloned a github repository of a package, `MDAnalysis`, which I also have installed under `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/MDAnalysis`.

I opened the cloned repository in PyCharm and set it as source root, like in the picture below:

[image: MDAnalysis as source root]

My problem: when I try to navigate to any submodule of `MDAnalysis`, PyCharm takes me to the submodule under the version that I have installed, instead of the submodule of the cloned repository.

Maybe I could fix this if I placed the source root first in the PYTHONPATH variable, but I don't know how to do this in the PyCharm environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns all I needed was to mark `package` as sources instead of `MDAnalysis`, and then clean the caches and restart.